# Reflection, dynamic. How to replace one object with another?

Tags: c#

I have an object like this

```
public class Simple
{
    public string Value
    {
      get { return GetProperty(); }
    }

    // different methods, fields, events, etc.
}
```

Possible to replace instance of the class *Simple* with equal object, but with setter?

How to implement ...

```
private object Substitution(object simple)
{
    object newSimple;

    // implementations

    newSimple.Value = "data";
    return newSimple;
}
```

To have something like this

```
public class Simple
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    // my methods, fields, events ...
}
```

I thought to create a class and inherit from SystemObject, then you can create different dynamic properties, but could not do :(

Or maybe try to inherit from this object (how?) and override the properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the definition or structure of a loaded type at runtime.

You could, potentially, make a *new type* that had a similar set of properties and fields, with the property setter added.  However, this is going to be of limited use in most cases, as the existing code will not understand the new type (since it's runtime generated), so would still be working off the existing type, which won't be compatible.

Typically, if you need runtime extensibility within a type, there are other options, including using a `Dictionary<T,U>`, or `dynamic` with `ExpandoObject`, or some other mechanism for storing "extra" information within a class that is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You couuld always use an interface, that only defines a property getter. Then in the implementation have a property setter?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IMyClass myA = new ClassA{ Property = "Class A" };

        Console.WriteLine(myA.Property);

        // can't do this
        // myA.Property = "New Property"; 

        // can do this
        (myA as ClassA).Property = "New Property"; 
        Console.WriteLine(myA.Property);
    }
}

interface IMyClass
{
    string Property { get; }
}

class ClassA : IMyClass
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

Failing that, you could do an user defined conversion using the explicit keyword, [more info at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EXPLICIT_CSHARPKEYWORD%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)